# What is the point of obtaining Curly's Panties?

Tags: cave-story

In Cave Story 3D I went into Curly's room in the Sandzone and picked up the item, "Curly's Panties". They are descriptionless and I could not find any use form them for the 3DS version. Do they have any use at all except for sitting in my inventory, taking up space?

Answer (score 9):

It looks like in Cave Story+ on the PC and Wii, at least, finding them unlocks [Curly Mode](http://cavestory.wikia.com/wiki/Curly_Story) from the main menu. It's kind of unclear whether or not that mode is present in the 3DS version; I've seen comments on the internet going both ways.

In the [PC version](http://strategywiki.org/wiki/Cave_Story/Items#Unobtainable_Items), they do have a description, which ends with:

> They have no use.

Regardless of which version you're playing, they're not used during the game itself so they'll just sit there in your inventory taking up space.

Comment: Don't you also have to find the lipstick to get Curly Mode?

Comment: No. Chako's lipstick is just an easter egg.

Answer (score 3):

Obtaining them unlocks the secret achievement [Panty Raider](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/43991) and opens up [Curly's Story](http://cavestory.wikia.com/wiki/Curly_Story) mode.

Comment: That was on the PC version not the 3DS one.